# A non well formed numeric value encountered After Formatted by number_format() function

Tags: laravel, number-formatting, php-7.2

I am using Accessor for format my number value. Problem start when i try to calculate the formatted value because number_format() function return a string value. Is there any alternative way to format the number value and calculate the value also.

```
class Order extends Model

{
    protected $fillable = ['order_quantity'];

    public function getOrderQuantityAttribute($value)
    {
        return number_format($value);
    }
}
```

Error shown when i try to calculate like,

```
$order->order_quantity * 100;   
//$order->order_quantity value is 10,000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this will help you. using `str_replace` remove comma from string.

```
$newOrderQuantity = str_replace(',', '', $order->order_quantity); // converting to "10000"
```

so on, you can use `(int)$newOrderQuantity` for calculation.

Comment: Thank you ! Your Solution worked. One more question. Is there anyway to access the raw data after used Accessor.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli i am not getting question exactly. may be you are talking about getting original raw data (Before using accessor data). `$model->getOriginal('column-name-here');` can do it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes ! I am talking about getting original raw data (Before using accessor data).

Comment: use this : `$model->getOriginal('column-name-here')`

Answer (score 0):

just replace ',' with '' :

```
   str_replace(',','',$order->order_quantity) *10
```

Comment: After do this ((int) $order->order_quantity), It return 10 only. it worked until (,) comes.